# How to copy in the vim to gnome desktop

Tags: vim, copy, global

As the title, I use `archlinux` and installed `Gnome`.I want to copy the contect to `Google Chrome`, how can I do?

I have tried "+y or "*y but didn't work.
Maybe I should recomplied it but I don't know how to do it.

Can somebody helps me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"y" copy is internal to vim, it does not work with your X clipboard, try selecting the text you want to copy, and then pressing Shift+Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of inconsistencies between clipboards on Desktop machines, therefore `vim` has **two** registers: `*` and `+`.  Gnome shall use the clipboard at the `+` register, and `"+yy` (two yankes) and `"+p` do work on my `archlinux` in a GTK environment.

You can chek if your `vim` has the clipboard feature compiled in (community package on `archlinux` has it)

```
$ vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +toolbar
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
```

(if either `-clipboard` or `-xterm_clipboard` appears you have a `vim` without clipboard support)

---

### Arch Linux specific

In `archlinux` you need the packages `extra/gvim` and `extra/vim-runtime` to get the `vim` version with the clipboard registers compiled in.  Note that `extra/gvim` conflicts with `extra/vim` but there is nothing to worry, `extra/gvim` comes with `/usr/bin/vim` which works without an `X11` display.

---

Also, we do have a [vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) section of the site.  Question like this one are better asked there.

Comment: -clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard

does this mean i cannot do so?

Comment: Correct, `-clipboard` and `-xterm_clipboard` mean that your `vim` has not been compiled with the registers enabled.  I'm confident that in `archlinux` the package that has these compile in is `extra/gvim` not `extra/vim`.  I have update the answer a little to reflect this.

Comment: @edisonChen: From [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Installation) wiki: *The `gvim` package provides also the CLI version of Vim with the `+clipboard` feature.* As for the clipboard in Linux, see [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/96/6698) really great answer at the [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @grochmal , thanks to your answer.
I'll try to recompile it to make my vim.